# Web MIDI ⇆ JACK

Tags: software, midi

I'm using Google Chrome on Ubuntu, which provides good Web MIDI support. However, I use JACK for most audio apps, and I find that JACK MIDI ports don't show up in the Web MIDI devices - only ALSA ports show up there.

I can get around that using extra software like `a2jmidid` and the like, but I was wondering if Google Chrome has settings to connect to JACK natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that NO, Chrome does not support JACK. I've opened a feature request to add JACK support: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=668833. Feel free to star it there and help move it forward.